# Transform 1D List

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, transform

I'm new to python and I need to transform a list of number(0,1,2,3) into a 2D array. Basically, they both have the same row number however the value in the 1D list indicates it's column number in the 2D array. The value in the 2D list is marked with a 1. For example, a sample 1D list

```
list_1d = [1,0,3,2,0]

1
0
3
2
0
```

I need it to be transformed to,

```
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

I have created a 2D array of zeros,

```
array_2d = np.zeros((len(list_1d),4))
```

Kindly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like 1 & 2 result in the same row in `array_2d`, while 0 results in no 1 in that row, which doesn't match your description.

Comment: Under what circumstances could a 1 appear in the first column?

Comment: `array_2d[:][list_1d] = 1` However, its marking the first 4 rows and columns with a 1

Comment: @ScottHunter apologies, I have corrected the description

Comment: 1 & 2 *still* result in the same row in `array_2d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I wanted to optimize code by not using a for loop since my list has millions of elements."

In that case, use numpy:

```
>>> list_1d = [1,0,3,2,0]
>>> mat = np.zeros((len(list_1d),4))
>>> mat[range(len(list_1d)), list_1d] = 1
>>> mat
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Because this approach avoids looping at the python level, it should be fast even for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner

```
>>> np.array([[ 1 if i == n else 0 for i in range(4)] for n in list_1d])
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

It uses a nested couple of comprehensions to do what you need.  The width of the array is hardwired (the `range(4)`)

Comment: you could avoid harcoding the size by using `max(list_1d) + 1` instead of 4

Answer (score 0):

assuming the wanted result in the question is not exact, you could do something like this:

```
list_1d = [1,0,3,2,0]

x_size = max(list_1d) + 1
y_size = len(list_1d)

matrix = []
for y in range(y_size):
    line = []
    for x in range(x_size):
        line.append(1 if x == list_1d[y] else 0)
    matrix.append(line)

print matrix
```

it prints `[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]`

Comment: Ideally, I wanted to optimize code by not using a for loop since my list has millions of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1d = [1,0,3,2,0]
```

How tall should the matrix be?

> `height` is the number of elements in the 1d list.

```
height = len(list_1d)
```

How wide should the matrix be?

> `width` is the number of elements in each inner list.

```
width = max(list_1d)
```

What should the value of each inner list element be?

> 0 most of the time.

When should a matrix element not be zero?

> When its row is its original index and its column is its original value.

Can you express that as a Boolean?

```
index == value
```

Can you express that as an int?

> Just cast the bool to an int.

What is the definition of a row?

```
[int(value == index) for index in range(1 + width)]
```

What does it look like for all values?

```
[[int(value == index) for index in range(1 + width)] for value in list_1d]
```

Demonstrate:

```
>>> width=max(list_1d)
>>> [[int(value == index) for index in range(1 + width)] for value in list_1d]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```